# swap control and caps lock key within emacs, operating system : ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

Is it possible to swap control key and caps lock key within emacs, not system wide in ubuntu.

In OS X we can do

`(setq mac-option-modifier 'super
            mac-command-modifier 'meta)`

for swapping alt and command key.

so is there any variables which we can set for swapping ctrl and caps key in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way provided by Emacs to do that under X11.  Maybe X11 does offer a way to change the keyboard mapping for a particular application nowadays, but I've never of it.